# For each group add a new shifted column based on the value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the dataframe below, I am trying to add a new shifted column based on yes/no value in the column start. However, my attempts are not really effective.

```
id     Name     type    start
AAA    A         xx      yes
AAA    B         yy      no
AAA    C         xx      no
BBB    C         xx      yes
BBB    D         zz      no
BBB    B         yy      no
```

In the dataframe above, given the value "no" in column "start", I would like to add a new shifted column with the value from "Name", as well as change the value on the column "Name" itself.

Example of the expected output (the column start can be deleted after the operation)

```
id     Name     type      NAG   
AAA    A         xx        B
AAA    A         yy        C
BBB    C         xx        D
BBB    C         zz        B
```

Even better (but this I can also fix it using a dictionary afterwards, probably not worth including it unless you have a better solution):

```
id     Name     type      NAG   typeNAG  
AAA    A         xx        B       yy
AAA    A         xx        C       xx
BBB    C         xx        D       zz
BBB    C         xx        B       yy
```

My very poor attempt:

```py
def n_issue(row):
    if row['start'] == "no":
        return row['issueLabel']
    else:
        pass

ag["nag"] = ag(n_issue, axis=1)
```

But using the above I cannot shift the column..

Any solution is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the folowing:

```py
m = df["start"] == "yes"
res = (
    df[m].merge(df[~m], on="id", suffixes=("", "NAG"))
    .drop(columns=["start", "startNAG"])
)
```

- Merge `df` with itself on the column `id`, but on the left only with `"yes"`-rows and on the right only with `"no"`-rows. Use suffixes that yield something close to what you want.
- Drop the `start`-columns.

Result for the sample:

```
    id Name type NameNAG typeNAG
0  AAA    A   xx       B      yy
1  AAA    A   xx       C      xx
2  BBB    C   xx       D      zz
3  BBB    C   xx       B      yy
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
# Duplicate Name and type columns
df['NAG'] = df['Name']
df['typeNAG'] = df['type']

# Delete Name and type values where start=no
df['Name'] = df['Name'][df['start']=='yes']
df['type'] = df['type'][df['start']=='yes']

# Fill the empty cells with the cell above
df.ffill(inplace=True)

# Delete the start=yes rows and the start column
df = df[df['start']=='no']
df.drop(['start'], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
id     Name     type      NAG   typeNAG  
AAA    A         xx        B       yy
AAA    A         xx        C       xx
BBB    C         xx        D       zz
BBB    C         xx        B       yy
```